# Password reminder prompt - combine vb and hta

Tags: vbscript, scripting, hta, group-policy

I am trying to workout how I can combine these two scripts. I want to pass the value from the vbs script of the password remaining days to the hta file. I wouldnt mind a nicer web page interface as opposed to a message box if the users password has less than 7 days.

Any ideas?

https://www.reddit.com/r/usefulscripts/comments/4dc7pk/htavbscript_password_expiration_notification/

And this

```
'==========================================
' Check for password expiring notification
'==========================================
' First, get the domain policy.
'==========================================
Dim oDomain
Dim oUser
Dim maxPwdAge
Dim numDays
Dim warningDays
warningDays = 7

Set LoginInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")  
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & LoginInfo.UserName & "")  
strDomainDN = UCase(LoginInfo.DomainDNSName) 
strUserDN = LoginInfo.UserName
'========================================
' Check if password is non-expiring.
'========================================
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000
intUserAccountControl = objUser.Get("userAccountControl")
If intUserAccountControl And ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
    'WScript.Echo "The password does not expire."
Else

    Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & strDomainDN)
    Set maxPwdAge = oDomain.Get("maxPwdAge")
    '========================================
    ' Calculate the number of days that are
    ' held in this value.
    '========================================
    numDays = CCur((maxPwdAge.HighPart * 2 ^ 32) + _
                    maxPwdAge.LowPart) / CCur(-864000000000)
    'WScript.Echo "Maximum Password Age: " & numDays

    '========================================
    ' Determine the last time that the user
    ' changed his or her password.
    '========================================
    Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUserDN)
    '========================================
    ' Add the number of days to the last time
    ' the password was set.
    '========================================
    whenPasswordExpires = DateAdd("d", numDays, oUser.PasswordLastChanged)
    fromDate = Date
    daysLeft = DateDiff("d",fromDate,whenPasswordExpires)

    'WScript.Echo "Password Last Changed: " & oUser.PasswordLastChanged
    if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then
        Msgbox "Your network password expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "Once logged in, press CTRL-ALT-DEL and" & chr(13) & "select the 'Change a password' option", 0, "PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!"
    End if
End if
'========================================
' Clean up.
'========================================
Set oUser = Nothing
Set maxPwdAge = Nothing
Set oDomain = Nothing
```

Comment: That is not VB.NET code.

Comment: oops sorry, thanks

Comment: You are trying? And what have you tried already? `daysLeft` gives you your parameter for the hta. Simply call it with it.

Comment: thanks. My brain was fading yesterday. Managed to get what I needed